# mod_geoip2 and php pecl-geoip: how can i query by ip address?

Tags: php, apache2, geoip

how can i query the geoip database using php?

I have apache2 with mod_geoip2 installed and the pecl extension geoip PHP 5.3.

i want to search the country of the ip address i have as a parameter, not to query my own ip address.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the [`geoip_country_code_by_name`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) function could do the trick : it takes a hostname or IP address as a parameter, and returns the corresponding country-code.

If you pass the IP address you have for that parameter *(and not your own)*, it should do what you're asking for.